# RegFree COM: CoClass should return an object instance of a type from another assembly

Tags: c#, delphi, com, manifest, regfreecom

I am able to successfully achieve RegFree COM using application manifest as OneToOne relationship means there's no dependency for my SideBySide assembly that my native application to be aware of. I am able to instantiate, do call etc., without any problem.

And now, I tried to add one dependency to my existing SxS assembly to return that interface object to native application from the depending assembly. Here's my structure after adding a dependency to `TlbTest.dll` to return `IDep` from `TlbTestDep.dll` assembly.

[image: ProjectStructure]

When I launch the application, I started facing the SideBySide error as below.

Am I missing something ? How to get this working. As we need to go without registration. We have multiple version of software to be installed in the same system. Can anyone please help on this ?

[image: Error]

Contents of `DelphiProgram.exe.manifest`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

 <dependency>

   <dependentAssembly>

     <assemblyIdentity
       name="TlbTest"
       version="1.0.0.0"
       processorArchitecture="x86"
      />

   </dependentAssembly>

 </dependency>

</assembly>
```

Contents of `TlbTest.dll -> app.manifest`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" 
                      name="TlbTest"
                      processorArchitecture="x86"/>
    
    <clrClass clsid="{4BA0A087-3D5F-4BE9-8629-2C1C42674487}"
              runtimeVersion="v4.0.30319"
              threadingModel="Both"
              progid="TlbTest.Service"
              name="TlbTest.Service"></clrClass>
    
</assembly>
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is run sxstrace.exe when running your program to find out what the problem is. sxstrace.exe is sort of clunky in that it takes 2 or three steps to troubleshoot because you have to go into listening/collecting mode, stop, and then convert binary data to text data. However, it will generally give a useable message of what it cannot find--like not finding a manifest or file. Where is the interface defined in the assembly manifest?

Comment: Sure. Will try that. 